# Why does printf ignore the IFS when printing out the result of my script?

Tags: bash, wildcards, printf

This is a follow up to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14197202/1178669) posted on SO.

I've written a script called `except` which should print all filenames / directories except the ones given like so.

```
$ ls
a b c d
$ rm $(except b d)
$ ls
b d
```

The script I've written so far looks like this

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob

old_ifs=$IFS
IFS='|'
matches="!($*)"
IFS=' '

printf '%s' $matches
IFS=$old_ifs
```

This works more or less but the main problem is that printf doesn't seem to respect `IFS` set to  (blank).

It just prints them without a space between. If I instead use echo, it works (except for the added newline). But for compatibility reasons I want to use printf for this task. How can I achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

I also tried using the `%q` modifier which also didn't result in the desired output.

```
printf '%q' $matches
```

Comment: What about leaving out `IFS` and use just `printf '%s ' $matches`? (I mean include a literal space in the format string.)

Comment: @manatwork While that would work I don't want the extra blank behind the last match (I know I'm nitpicking here).

Comment: printf '%s' $something : will print the content of $something, with nothing around it. So it's just what you ask it to do... And use quotes (") to save and restore IFS, otherwise it won't be the exaxt content. ( OLDIFS="$IFS" ; .... ; IFS="$OLDIFS" ; ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> $ ls
> a b c d
> $ rm $(except b d)
> $ ls
> b d
> ```

That can't work, at least not reliably, because `"except"` cannot decide how the shell will split (and further expand) its output before passing it to the `rm` command.

To answer your question, printf doesn't use `$IFS`. The only command that uses IFS is `read`. Other than that, $IFS is used by the shell for word splitting and to join the positional arguments in `"$*"`.

You probably want:

```
 printf '%s ' $matches
```

Or

```
 printf '%s\n' $matches
```

But again, in

```
 rm $(except a b)
```

The shell that interprets that command line will split the output of `except` according to its own `$IFS` (by default space, tab or newline, which is why using space or `\n` above makes no difference) and will also expand the wildcards in there.

So if the files other than `a` and `b` are `"this file.txt"` and `**a**`, `except` will output `"this file.txt **a** "` and you will end up trying to remove `this`, `file.txt` and `a` (since `**a**` will expand to all the files with `a` in their name).

If you want to join the matches with spaces without the trailing space, you could do:

```
IFS=
set -- $matches
IFS=' '
matches="$*"
```